# git pull with clean local repo causes merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull

**Update**: This turned out to be a bug in the version of SmartGit I'm using (version 3.0.11) - an application which is similar to gitk.  The "Pushable Commits" list is modified after doing a "git pull" and some local commits not yet pushed are accidentally removed from this UI list.  This caused the confusion described in this post where it appeared the only commit which was not pushed was the "Merge commit".

---

I pushed changes to a remote (on GitHub).  Two other devs pushed a few commits after me.  I had absolutely no local changes or commits and did a "git pull".

Immediately, after it pulled down the changes, it forced me to do a merge commit (allowing me to type the optional message).  I've been using Git for ~2 years and I have yet to encounter this situation where pulling down changes into a clean local repo would force a merge commit.  The two times this occurred over the past week, I wasn't sure what to do so I pushed this merge commit immediately both times with no issues (!?).

On our team, we have a mix of some devs who prefer rebasing and others who use git pull. I'm wondering if it's possibly related (even though we've had this setup for over a year and I have not encountered this prior to a week ago).  I use git pull.

The image below shows the history.

[image: Merge commit]

My original commit pushed is the bottom dot on the purple line.  Two other devs pushed after me and upon pulling their changes it created the top "Merge Branch" commit in my local repo (on the same purple line).

Comment: Try inspecting the merge commit and its parent commits in a tool like `gitk`. You should see two parent commits with different hashes.

Comment: RE your image: And the remote branch you pulled from is pointed at the highlighted one?

Comment: This is all the same remote branch on github.  Ignore the highlighted commit (I just highlighted it by accident while inspecting parents etc).  The top commit (above the highlighted one) is the merge commit it created locally that I was forced to push.

Comment: I was asking what commit the branch you pulled from was pointing at. Your local branch was obviously pointing at the on in the bottom left.

Comment: I guess that's what I don't understand.  At the time I pushed the bottom commit, shouldn't my local and the remote be equivalent?  I.e. in order for someone else to push, they must first pull (fetch or whatever) my changes up to the bottom commit.  I don't understand how the remote can be pointing to a different commit.

Comment: Well, you didn’t have to push in the first place. When you pull something, and you notice something odd, then don’t push it but inspect it first. Git is distributed, so you decide when to pull or push commits.

Comment: I would imagine if I inspected it, I would see exactly what's in that image.  The parents would be my original commit (bottom left) and the commit from the red path.  I'm not sure how I would proceed if I didn't push that.

Comment: To clarify, if I discard it, would I perhaps lose the history of the commits on the red and green paths?  I certainly didn't want that to happen.

Comment: No, after pulling everything from the remote is within your locally stored remote branches (origin/master etc.). So whatever you do, you do not lose *anything* (and you could always fetch it again too). Unless you push, nothing you do locally will end up on the remote either. So after fetching/pulling, you are free to play around as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your image for even longer, I realized something obvious. Let’s name the commits A to E from bottom to top to make it easier.

So here’s the thing: Before pulling, your local branch was pointing at `A` which was the commit you had locally.

When looking at commit D however, you can see that the red line does not end in `A` but somewhere before (the screenshot is not showing that). So that commit was not based on `A` and as such you could not fast-forward when pulling. You had to create a merge commit instead.

Now you mentioned that you did push `A` before, so that’s a bit odd. If you really pushed it and `D` was published already, your push would have failed, and you had to merge it first. If `D` was not published already, your push would have went through, but then the author of `D` would have to merge it before being able to push it.

As you neither of that happened and you had to create a merge later when you pulled, the only reason left would be that you actually never pushed your commit `A`.

Note that committing does not automatically push a commit. As I said in the comments, unless you push/pull, everything you do is completely local. And only when you do push or pull, commits are actually transferred to or from the remote.

(The other option would be that the dev pushing `D` *did* get a conflict but chose to force-push instead, removing your commit from the remote repository. If you are using GitHub, this should be visible from that user’s activity log.)

Comment: I definitely did push A as it shows up on github.  However, A and B share the same parent even though B was pushed after A (dev who pushed B uses rebasing).  At that point in time, "A" might have been essentially been erased.  When I inspected the local history of the dev who pushed B, his local history does not show A at all.

Comment: Well, even if you use rebasing, you can’t push rebased commits if they overwrite the already pushed history without using force. You would get an error message otherwise (and you really shouldn’t do it anway). That the dev of B didn’t have `A` tells you that he didn’t pull first (because he would have gotten `A` then), but he also shouldn’t be able to push then. – Is this a public project on GitHub?

Comment: Sorry no it's a private repo.

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  It's possible he may have pushed before me (but locally I committed first).  Dev who pushed B stated he did not do a force push.  And I definitely did not do a force push.  Even though I'm still not sure how this is possible, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: I've looked into this a bit further...  I believe "git reflog show origin/master" will show when I actually did push.  And it seems like I never pushed commit A which would explain all of this.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 0):

The big thing to remember with this is that `git pull` is a combination of two commands, `git fetch` and `git merge`. Also your local master branch is not the same branch as the remote master.

Someone pushed changes to the remote branch after you pushed your changes.  So when you pulled from the remote.  Git updated the `HEAD` of the remote branch and then merged that into your local branch.  Merging causes a commit to happen so you will end up with a merge commit.

If you had reset your branch to the commit that you originally pushed and then did `git pull --rebase` you would find that commits that the other developers would have added would be in line with your branch and you would not have a merge commit.

Generally these merge commits are benign but occasionally they can cause some trouble.

From your comment, when you pushed your local had one or more commits than your remote.  Immediately after you pushed then they were equivalent.